# PropertyTypeError when I try to checkout using Stripe and use-shopping-cart with Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

When I go to checkout it tell me
`Invalid value with type "undefined" was received for stripe. Valid type for stripe is "string".`

regarding

```
const result = await redirectToCheckout(data.id)
```

To be more precise I think it has a problem with redirectToCheckout. Can u help me out?

cart-summary.tsx where I list all the items, prices and everything regarding the items from sanity.io:

```
"use client"


import { useState } from "react"
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react"
import { formatCurrencyString, useShoppingCart } from "use-shopping-cart"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

export function CartSummary() {

  const{ formattedTotalPrice, totalPrice, cartDetails, cartCount, redirectToCheckout } = useShoppingCart()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const isDisabled =  loading || cartCount === 0
  const shippingAmount =  cartCount! > 0 ? 500 : 0
  const totalAmount = totalPrice! + shippingAmount


  async function onCheckout() {
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await fetch('/api/checkout', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(cartDetails),
  })
  const data = await response.json()
  const result = await redirectToCheckout(data.id)
  if (result?.error) {
    console.error(result)
  }
  setLoading(false)
}

  return (
    <section
      aria-labelledby="summary-heading"
      className="mt-16 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 px-4 py-6 shadow-md dark:border-gray-900 dark:bg-black sm:p-6 lg:col-span-5 lg:mt-0 lg:p-8"
    >
      <h2 id="summary-heading" className="text-lg font-medium">
        Order summary
      </h2>

      <dl className="mt-6 space-y-4">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
          <dt className="text-sm">{formattedTotalPrice}</dt>
          <dd className="text-sm font-medium">Subtotal Amount</dd>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 pt-4 dark:border-gray-600">
          <dt className="flex items-center text-sm">
            <span>Shipping estimate</span>
          </dt>
          <dd className="text-sm font-medium">{formatCurrencyString({currency:"RON", value: shippingAmount}) }</dd>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 pt-4 dark:border-gray-600">
          <dt className="text-base font-medium">Order total</dt>
          <dd className="text-base font-medium">{formatCurrencyString({currency:"RON", value: totalAmount}) }</dd>
        </div>
      </dl>

      <div className="mt-6">
        <Button onClick={onCheckout} className="w-full" disabled={isDisabled}>
        {loading &&   <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />}
          { loading ? "Loading..." :  "Checkout"}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

And this is the route i created for checkout that is in the api/checkout folder where I specify stripe what to POST:

route.tsx:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
// @ts-ignore
import { validateCartItems } from "use-shopping-cart/utilities"

import { inventory } from "@/config/inventory"
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe"

export async function POST(request: Request ) {
  const cartDetails = await request.json()
  const lineItems = validateCartItems(inventory, cartDetails)
  const origin  = request.headers.get("origin")
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    submit_type: "pay",
    mode: "payment",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    billing_address_collection: "auto",
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["RO"]
    },
    line_items: lineItems,
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate: "shr_1NH12xCCdOHTtB3CM44Ngbmk",
      }
    ],

    success_url: `${origin}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${origin}/cart`,
  })
  return NextResponse.json(session)
}
```

Tried Debugging but couldn't find the issue

[image: This is the error when i click checkout]

[image: And this is how it looks when]

[image: This is the console]

Comment: Could you please specify exactly where you see the error? (a screenshot would be great)

Comment: @vanya Done with putting the screenshots up

Comment: It seems like use-shopping-card can't find your Stripe public key: https://github.com/dayhaysoos/use-shopping-cart/blob/0484dadfa134faa0b446228e7778701c26b660b7/use-shopping-cart/core/middleware/stripe.js#LL40C16-L40C31

You need to make sure your Stripe publishable key is used somewhere on the frontend: https://useshoppingcart.com/docs/welcome/getting-started-serverless

Answer (score 1):

If I remember this project tutorial correctly. The error is due to stripe publishable key not being used correctly. Go to your components folder and under the file called providers.tsx, make sure you're secret key is spelled correctly

```html
"use client"

import { CartProvider } from "use-shopping-cart"

import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster"
import { TailwindIndicator } from "@/components/tailwind-indicator"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/theme-provider"

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export function Providers({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <CartProvider
      currency="CAD"
      shouldPersist
      cartMode="checkout-session"
      stripe={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY!} // Make sure this is inserted correctly
    >
      <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
        <Toaster />
        {children}
        <TailwindIndicator />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CartProvider>
  )
}
```